# converting dictionary to string and string to dict

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
>>> word_array = defaultdict(list)
>>> word_array['first'].append(1)
>>> word_array['first'].append(2)
>>> word_array
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'first': [1, 2]})
```

I converted it to string the whole data structure, but when i try to convert it from string i can't, i get the following:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(str(word_array))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'first': [1, 2]})
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any better solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want to do here is *serialize* your data structure into a string, and then *deserialize* it back into a data structure. Don't use things like `ast.literal_eval` in production. Just use `pickle`:

```
import pickle
from collections import defaultdict

word_array = defaultdict(list)
word_array['first'].append(1)
word_array['first'].append(2)

s = pickle.dumps(word_array)
other = pickle.loads(s)

print other
```

Gives:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'first': [1, 2]})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about having it be a `defaultdict` on decode then use `json`. If you *do* care, then also use `json`, but pass a function to be used on object decode via `object_hook`.

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> d['first'] = [1, 2]
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"first": [1, 2]}'
>>> json.loads('{"first": [1, 2]}')
{u'first': [1, 2]}
>>> def ddoh(d):
...   res = collections.defaultdict(list)
...   res.update(d)
...   return res
... 
>>> json.loads('{"first": [1, 2]}', object_hook=ddoh)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'first': [1, 2]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to serialize/deserialize objects ? If so, the [Pickle python module](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickle) is made for you.

Answer (score 0):

When saving it in a deserialized format is not possible, this is a solution that worked for me:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import ast

teststring = "{'MATERIAL': ['a', 'b']}"
a = ast.literal_eval(teststring)
d = defaultdict(list,a)

print(d)
```

gives

```
>>> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'first': [1, 2]})
```

I am importing the defaultdict as a string from an excel file and for readability reasons deserializing was not an option.